# Laravel função find() dando erro

Tags: php, laravel

Quando lanço uma busca com uma id que existe no banco, ele funciona normalmente.

> Laravel 5.6

```
    public function findProduto($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::find($id)->with('imagemgame')->first();
    return $dados_check = $produto->count()>0 ? $produto : false ;
}
```

porém quando lanço uma busca com uma id que não existe no banco, em vez de retornar "false", ele retorna um erro, parece estar dando algo errado no find ou algo parecido.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function find() on null
```

Model-> Produtos

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Models\ImageUploads;

class Produto extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

public $timestamps = true;

protected $table = 'produtos';

protected $fillable = [
    'titulo', 'status', 'console', 'edicao', 'genero', 'classificacao', 'custo', 'venda', 'promocao',
    'indatepromo', 'outdatepromo', 'quantidade', 'descricao', 'produtora', 'lancamento',
    'idioma', 'legenda', 'onplayers', 'offplayers', 'obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3', 'video',
];

protected $hidden = ['custo'];

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// RELACIONAMENTOS /////////////////////////////////////////////
public function imagemgame(){
    return $this->hasMany(ImageUpload::class, 'produtos_id', 'id')->orderBy('capa', '1');
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analisando o seu código tem alguns problemas, exemplo: quando se utiliza o `find` que é o retorno da informação pelo ***chave primária*** da sua tabela se o dados não for encontrado é retornado `null` e logo após você faz um `with` que não existe, esse é o motivo do problema e da exceção lançada, depois dentro do método no momento do retorno você colocou `count`, não existe esse método porque não é uma lista é um dado único, então também tem que trocar a critica e resolvi propror um exemplo minimo:

```
public function findProduto($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::with('imagemgame')->where('id', $id)->first();
    return is_null($produto) ? false: $produto;
}
```

***Observação:*** eu fiz um `where` e coloquei o nome da **chave primária**, você deve também colocar o mesmo nome, acabei deixando `id` que é um padrão, mas, claro que o nome pode se outro.

---

Também pode ser feito assim:

```
public function findProduto($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::find($id);
    if ($produto)
    {
        $produto->load('imagemgame'); //carregamento a relação
        return $produto;
    }
    return false;
}
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)</sub>

Comment: mesmo se eu tirar tudo.. e deixar só Produtos::find($id)->first() ele da erro

Comment: Porque `find` é o termino do comando, não precisa colocar `first()` o find já faz isso pra você @MichaelCosta

Comment: porem se eu usar where('id', '=', $id ai sim.. ele retorna null
não deveria retornarn null também usando o find($id) ?

Comment: ata entendi.. vou testar aqui

Comment: Se você digitar `Produtos::find($id);` é assim que deve ser feito, ou retorna o objeto da classe ou retorna `null.` @MichaelCosta

Comment: @MichaelCosta editei colocando outra forma, acho legal essa também.

Comment: Top mano! era isso mesmo. obrigado!!!

Comment: Legal usando o load.. não conhecia dessa maneira. vou usar assim agora. vlw mano! obrigado!